# Better way of doing: Always get a range of 6 Items out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

i need a little bit algorithm help.

I want to extract a range of 6 items out of an array. Starting point is a given index, if possible i want to get the items evenly split up before and after the given index.

I already did it, but i search for a more elegant way than just shifting the range. How can i improve my code?

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];
const area = 7;
const currentIndex = 5;
const arrayLength = array.length;


let rangeBegin = currentIndex - Math.floor((area - 1) / 2);
let rangeEnd = currentIndex + Math.ceil((area - 1) / 2);

if (rangeBegin < 0) {
  const offset = -rangeBegin;
  rangeBegin += offset;
  rangeEnd += offset;
}

if (rangeEnd >= arrayLength) {
  const offset = rangeEnd - arrayLength;
  rangeBegin -= offset;
  rangeEnd -= offset;
}
slicedArray = array.slice(rangeBegin, rangeEnd);

console.log(slicedArray)
```

https://playcode.io/377252?tabs=script.js,preview,console

Comment: Look like you need `https://codereview.stackexchange.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the index by subtracting the half size and take a max value for negative indices and a min value for indices which are greater than the array length minus the size of the wanted sub array.

> ```
>  value  array                           index  adj  max  min
>  -----  ------------------------------  -----  ---  ---  ---
>             v                              
>     2    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10     1    -1    0    0
>         [             ]
>
>                      v        
>     5    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10     4     2    2    2
>               [             ]
>
>                                     vv        
>    10    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10     9     7    7    5
>                        [              ]
> ```

```js
function getSub(array, index, size) {
    if (size >= array.length) return array;
    var pivot = Math.floor(index - (size - 1) / 2),
        max = Math.max(pivot, 0),
        min = Math.min(max, array.length - size);
    return array.slice(min, min + size);
}

console.log(...getSub([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 1, 5));
console.log(...getSub([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 4, 5));
console.log(...getSub([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 9, 5));

console.log(...getSub([1, 2, 3, 4], 1, 5));
console.log(...getSub([1, 2, 3, 4], 4, 5));
console.log(...getSub([1, 2, 3, 4], 9, 5));
```

Comment: The validity is difficult to see in second example for using 1-based values in a 0-based array. What happens if array.length < size?

Comment: @greybeard, good catch. in this case the wanted size has to be adjusted as well.

Comment: sorry, I ment when size>=array.length

Comment: @NinaScholz this is a nice solution to this problem. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17];
const area = 7;
const currentIndex = 5;
const arrayLength = array.length;


let rangeBegin = currentIndex - Math.floor((area - 1 ) /2);
if(rangeBegin < 0) {
  rangeBegin = 0;
}
let rangeEnd = rangeBegin + area - 1;
if(rangeEnd >= arrayLength) {
  rangeEnd = arrayLength;
  rangeBegin = arrayLength - area;
}

slicedArray = array.slice(rangeBegin, rangeEnd);
```

**!!! This code not checks if length of array lower than area we need.**